# Question about the relation between the Weierstrass equation and weighted projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, projective-space, toric-geometry, string-theory

I am reading a review on Toric Geometry for string theorists by Harald Skarke ([arXiv:hep-th/9806059](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9806059)). In section 3, the author says

> A standard way of describing an elliptic curve is by embedding it into $\mathbb{P}^2 = (\mathbb{C}^3\setminus\{0\})/(\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\})$.....The elliptic curve is embedded in this space via the Weierstrass equation
>   $$ \label{eq:w1}y^2 z = x^3 + a x z^2 + b z^3$$
>
> An alternative description can be given in terms of the weighted projective space $\mathbb{P}^{(2,3,1)}$ defined just like $\mathbb{P}^2$, but with the equivalence relation changed to
>
> $$(x, y, z) \sim (\lambda^2 x, \lambda^3 y, \lambda z) \quad \text{  for any } \lambda \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$$
>
> and the Weierstrass equation changed to
>
> $$\label{eq:w2}y^2 = x^3 + a x z^4 + b z^6$$

**Questions**

1. Given the description of the two projective spaces as embeddings in $\mathbb{C}^3$, how does one obtain the two Weierstrass equations?
2. Is there a way to transform the first Weierstrass equation into the other?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Given the standard affine cubic in Weierstrass form $y^2=x^3+g_2x+g_3$, the way to derive the corresponding equation in projective space $y^2 z = x^3 + a x z^2 + b z^3$ is called "homogenization". It's quite simple, you just add enough powers of an extra variable to make sure every term has the same degree.

Comment: Thanks @ziggurism; yes, I figured that. But how do you go from the equation describing the elliptic curve over that is a fiber over $\mathbb{P}^2$ to the one describing the fiber over $\mathbb{P}^{(2,3,1)}$?

Comment: $(x, y, z) \sim (\lambda^2 x, \lambda^3 y, \lambda z) $ means you want to add some $z$ in $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ such that each term has the same weighted degree $\deg_W$, where $\deg_W(x) = 2,\deg_W(y)=3,\deg_W(z)=1$, $\deg_W(y^2)=6,\deg_W(x^3)=6,\deg_W(ax)=2$,$\deg_W(b)=0$, which leads to $y^2  = x^3 + a x z^4 + b z^6$

Comment: The isomorphism between all those things is obtained by setting $z=1$, ie. $(x,y,z) \mapsto (\frac{x}{z^2},\frac{y}{z^3},1)$ for the weighted one, except for the case $z=0$ where you need to repair/extend by continuity

Comment: Here are two sets of notes you may find useful: [1](https://thosgood.github.io/pdfs/general/introduction-to-wps.pdf), [2](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masda/surf/more/grad.pdf)